# Powershell - Overiding Arguments Relase definition

Tags: powershell, arguments

I am trying to create a Release definition in TFS 2017 with powershell script

I am runing a powershell script that has to find a path of a setParameters.xml file which it does and it suppose to over ride all the tokens but the it just ignores the loop and the arguments stay the same.

Script code:

```
$vars = Get-ChildItem -path env:*

# read in the setParameters file
$contents = Get-Content -Path $paramsFilePath

# perform a regex replacement

$newContents = "";
$contents | % {
    $line = $_
    if ($_ -match "__(\w+)__") {
        $setting = Get-ChildItem -path env:* | ? { $_.Name -eq $Matches[1]  }
        if ($setting) {
            Write-Verbose -Verbose ("Replacing key {0} with value from environment" -f $setting.Name)
            $line = $_ -replace "__(\w+)__", $setting.Value
        }
    }
    $newContents += $line + [Environment]::NewLine
}
```

Why is the loop being skiped and how could i fix it so it overwrites the arguments in SetParameters.xml file?

Comment: Why do you use regex replacement instead of PowerShells builtin xml capabilities? Ans how is this related to tfs?

Comment: I am creating a Release definition. in TFS...

Comment: Yeah, that's the script for. But _your question_ does not relate to tfs.

Comment: Generally script looks OK. So you need to do troubleshooting. You are saying loop is getting skipped. Which loop? If you refer to loop starting with `$contents | % {` then it means you have no content in your `$paramsFilePath` - file is empty or variable is wrong. If that's not the failing loop, then add one more Write-Verbose to identify which `if` is failing to behave as you want.

Comment: Would it be easier/better to use Replace Tokens in Release definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I have ditched this powershell and used Replace Token step in Release definition.

I think its a more efficient way to replace tokens